# Executing `ls` on docker with a shared volume results in "No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm writing a node program that uses dockernode as the Docker client. The program creates a container with a volume that is bound to a directory on the host when the container is started.  One started, I attempt to print the contents of the shared volume to prove that it's working properly. However, I keep getting `(ls: /tmp/app: No such file or directory`.

Here is my code...

```
var Docker = require('dockerode'),
    docker = new Docker(),
    mkdirp = require('mkdirp'),
    volume = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/' + Date.now();

function handleError(action, err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error while ' + action + '...');
        console.error(err);
    }
}

mkdirp.sync(volume);

docker.createContainer({
    Image: 'ubuntu',
    Volumes: {
        '/tmp/app': {}
    }
}, function(err, container) {
    handleError('building', err);

    container.start({
        Binds: [volume + ':/tmp/app']
    }, function(err, data) {
        handleError('starting', err);

        container.exec({
            AttachStdout: true,
            AttachStderr: true,
            Tty: false,
            Cmd: ['/bin/ls', '/tmp/app']
        }, function(err, exec) {
            handleError('executing `ls /tmp/app`', err);

            exec.start(function(err, stream) {
                handleError('handling response from `ls /tmp/app`', err);

                stream.setEncoding('utf8');
                stream.pipe(process.stdout);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I've succeeded by doing this without exec, where I create the container, attach to it, start it with the `ls` command, wait for it to finish, and then kill it and remove it. But I'm looking to use exec so I can issue multiple commands once the container is running. I've been trying to piece this together from the examples in the dockerode library and the Docker remote API documentation. I just don't know where I'm going wrong.

For reference, here is the code without exec...

```
docker.createContainer({
    Image: 'ubuntu',
    Cmd: ['/bin/ls', '/tmp/app'],
    Volumes: {
        '/tmp/app': {}
    }
}, function(err, container) {
    console.log('attaching to... ' + container.id);

    container.attach({stream: true, stdout: true, stderr: true, tty: true}, function(err, stream) {
        handleError('attaching', err);

        stream.pipe(process.stdout);

        console.log('starting... ' + container.id);

        container.start({
            Binds: [volume + ':/tmp/app']
        }, function(err, data) {
            handleError('starting', err);
        });

        container.wait(function(err, data) {
            handleError('waiting', err);

            console.log('killing... ' + container.id);

            container.kill(function(err, data) {
                handleError('killing', err);

                console.log('removing... ' + container.id);

                container.remove(function(err, data) {
                    handleError('removing', err);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please ignore the callback hell that is developing. It's only temprorary.

Comment: The ubuntu image's CMD is bash, without being attached bash exits, have you tried doing the command.start with a long running process?

Comment: So I can successfully print the contents of the root directory by only changing the exec command to `Cmd: ['/bin/ls', '/']`. The issue seems to be that the volume in the container (`Volumes: {'/tmp/app': {}}`) isn't getting created. Is there a reason that the default bash command would not allow for that directory to get created?

Comment: Or maybe the volume is being created, but it's just not available when the exec command is issued? Could it be that the container is started with the binding and then stopped before being recreated for the exec call without the binding?

Comment: Instead of using the ubuntu image, I used the dockerfile/mysql image to guarantee that the process would be running indefinitely. Once I made that change, it worked as expected. So it must be that the call to `start` doesn't keep the container running when using the ubuntu image. The container must not be running when I try to call `exec` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had struggled with same issue for some time,but I found solution. It seems that Remote API do not accept command with arguments as one string, but you have to split each argument as new token in Cmd property array; for example with gcc:

```
"Cmd":["/bin/bash","-c","gcc -Wall -std=c99 hello.c -o hello.bin"]
```

After this modification it works correctly.

Official documentation could be better for Remote API configuration.

Comment: All of my Cmd properties are split up into multiple arguments. `Cmd: ['/bin/ls', '/tmp/app']`

Comment: I don't understand how this answer helps regarding the question.